# Solspace Calendar embed range not registering

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

For some reason we're getting a null set of data when the `{if segment_3 == "week"}` evaluates to true and its code is run:

// Base template

```
{if segment_3 == "day"} {!-- This works. --}
    {embed="calendar/event_landing" range_start="{segment_4}/{segment_5}/{segment_6}" range_end="{segment_4}/{segment_5}/{segment_6}"}
{/if}

{if segment_3 == "week"} {!-- This DOES NOT work. --}
    {embed="calendar/event_landing" range_start="{segment_4}/{segment_5}/{segment_6}" range_end="+1 week"}
{/if}

{if segment_3 == "month"} {!-- This works. --}
    {embed="calendar/event_landing" range_start="{segment_4}/{segment_5}/{segment_6}" range_end="+1 month"}
{/if}
```

// event_landing template

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="{embed:range_start}" date_range_end="{embed:range_end}" pad_short_weeks="n"}
    ...show events...
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

In our ajax call, we're changing the segments before we send them so all single digits receive preceeding 0s.

// JS

```
var s_2 = {segment_2} + "", // M
    s_3 = {segment_3} + "", // D
    s_4 = {segment_4} + ""; // Y

if (s_2.length == 1) { s_2 = "0" + s_2; }
if (s_3.length == 1) { s_3 = "0" + s_3; }

// Render the AJAX url before calling it
ajaxTarget = "/calendar/ajax/" + selectedRange + "/" + s_2 + "/" + s_3 + "/" + s_4 + "/";
```

For an example, when the value of our `ajaxTarget` var is

`/calendar/ajax/week/01/02/2014/`

the event data for the next 7 days is returned just fine, but if we change the value of `02` to `27`, resulting in

`/calendar/ajax/week/01/27/2014/`

no data is returned!

**Please note** that we've also tried using `+7 days` with the same results.

Any help on this would be appreciated~

---

EDIT 1:

I think I figured out the reason, but I don't know how to fix it:

I added this little bit of debug to the `event_landing` page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s4 = {segment_4} + "",
        s5 = {segment_5} + "",
        s6 = {segment_6} + "";

    console.log("/" + s4 + "/" + s5 + "/" + s6);
</script>
```

It's showing that the data is `/1/20/2014`, but this shouldn't be happening because we're adding (and checking) preceeding zeros before this is reached; they're just not showing up. Right  before the `$.ajax(...)` call, the the log shows the `ajaxTarget` as `/calendar/ajax/week/01/20/2014/`, so it's being changed during the request somehow :(

Comment: For completeness, can you tell us what version of Calendar and EE you are using? Also, have you tried the calendar code without any javascript/ajax to see if that works at least? Finally, why go to the trouble of adding/removing `0` through javascript when you could use `0`-containing segments directly?

Comment: Can you also show us your full js/ajax code? What is triggering the ajax, by the way? Where is the js code placed?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this, but i tracked it down to a bug in EE. Essentially, zero-padded numbers don't retain their padding, and trying to add those zeros back is really difficult. Here's my other thread about it: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/embedding-php-in-ee-tags-or-using-equivalent-expressions-in-php/18063?noredirect=1#18063

Comment: Ignoring js/ajax for a moment, you should be able to use Calendar with zero-padded numbers as segments in the URL, eg. /calendar/events/2014/01/07. I'm still wondering if something can't be tweaked in your javascript. If you can show more of the script, as well as tell us what is triggering the ajax, maybe there's a simple (or different) solution to your issue.

Comment: Have you also tried using this ajax script code: http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/190597/articles/119581-simple-jquery-ajax-script-template. You might need to tweak it for your needs, though.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your URL:

```
/calendar/ajax/week/01/02/2014/
```

Then this part of your code is incorrect because it's calling the wrong segments:

```
var s_2 = {segment_2} + "", // M
    s_3 = {segment_3} + "", // D
    s_4 = {segment_4} + ""; // Y
```

Should be:

```
var s_2 = {segment_4} + "", // M
    s_3 = {segment_5} + "", // D
    s_4 = {segment_6} + ""; // Y
```

Comment: That's kind of you to point out but that's actually referencing the segments for the current page URL, whereas the latter 4/5/6 reference the segments in the AJAX GET request and I simply omitted that fact. The end-user never sees a redirect to `/calendar/ajax/week/.../`, simply `/calendar/MM/DD/YYYY/`